# How can I convert text links into real links that the Google API strips out?

Tags: javascript, google-api, feedparser

```
google.load("feeds", "1");

function OnLoad() {

    // Create a feed control
    var feedControl = new google.feeds.FeedControl();

    // Add 1 feeds.
    feedControl.addFeed("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=SteveMartinToGo&count=2");

    // Draw it.
    feedControl.draw(document.getElementById("twitter_content"));

}

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
```

I'm using the Google FeedControl API to render Tweets from RSS.

It's probably not the best way to render tweets but Twitter's REST API has a rate limit and times out after its been hit a few times, which is quite annoying.

This seems pretty solid that it's just a RSS feed parser except that the Google API strips out the links and makes them into plain text. I would like to convert them back to links if possible.

Comment: I can't find any documentation for the .draw method, so I wonder if it has been depreciated since it was introduced in 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this is very useful, no rate limit issues and tweets look good.

http://jsfiddle.net/derek/Vjxt2/